# How to switch node js version?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have written a cloud function, which I want to deploy, but for deploying the function, I need to upgrade to the blaze plan which I don't want for now.

But, I can deploy my function if I don't use NodeJs 10.

Can someone please tell me how can i install/ switch to NodeJs 8 on my computer to deploy the function.

I tried to google this, but i couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question, In your `package.json` file inside functions directory, You can change the node version under engines.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```